# Показать заданные атрибуты товара на страницах архива и категорий в WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Я сделал вывод атрибутов товара на страницах архива и категорий.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'new_template_loop_product_meta', 20 );
function new_template_loop_product_meta() {
    global $product;
    
    if( ! is_object( $product ) ) { 
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
        $sku = $product->get_sku();
    }

    echo '<div class="pa">';
    echo '<span>Brand: </span>' . '<span class="pa-right">' . $product->get_attribute('pa_brand') . '</span><br />';
    echo '<span>Country: </span>' . '<span class="pa-right">' . $product->get_attribute('pa_contry') . '</span><br />';
    echo '<span>SKU: </span>' . '<span class="pa-right">' . $product->get_sku() . '</span><br />';
    echo '<span>Material: </span>' . '<span class="pa-right">' . $product->get_attribute('pa_material') . '</span><br />';
    echo '<span>Type: </span>' . '<span class="pa-right">' . $product->get_attribute('pa_product_type') . '</span><br />';
    echo '<span>Color: </span>' . '<span class="pa-right">' . $product->get_attribute('pa_color') . '</span><br />';
    echo '<span>Size: </span>' . '<span class="pa-right">' . $product->get_attribute('pa_size') . '</span><br />';
    echo '<span>Model: </span>' . '<span class="pa-right">' . $product->get_attribute('pa_model') . '</span><br />';
    echo '<span>Collection: </span>' . '<span class="pa-right">' . $product->get_attribute('pa_collection') . '</span><br />';
    echo '<span>Mechanism: </span>' . '<span class="pa-right">' . $product->get_attribute('pa_mechanism') . '</span><br />';
    echo '<span>Magnetic: </span>' . '<span class="pa-right">' . $product->get_attribute('pa_magnetic') . '</span><br />';
    echo '<span>Side: </span>' . '<span class="pa-right">' . $product->get_attribute('pa_side') . '</span><br />';
    echo '<span>Load: </span>' . '<span class="pa-right">' . $product->get_attribute('pa_load') . '</span><br />';
    echo '<span>Availability: </span>' . '<span class="pa-right">' . $product->get_attribute('pa_availability') . '</span>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Но на этих страницах показываются названия всех атрибутов, какие есть. Подскажите, как можно вывести только те атрибуты, что заданы тому или иному товару?

И наверное это уже второй вопрос. Как лучше оптимизировать код, чтобы не было лишних запросов к Базе с таким большим количеством атрибутов.

Буду рад вашей помощи!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот код, который выводит только те атрибуты, которые есть у данного товара:

```
<?php
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'new_template_loop_product_meta', 20 );

/**
 * Show product attributes.
 */
function new_template_loop_product_meta() {
    global $product;

    $attr_list = [
        'Brand'        => 'pa_brand',
        'Country'      => 'pa_country',
        'SKU'          => 'sku',
        'Material'     => 'pa_material',
        'Type'         => 'pa_product_type',
        'Color'        => 'pa_color',
        'Size'         => 'pa_size',
        'Model'        => 'pa_model',
        'Collection'   => 'pa_collection',
        'Mechanism'    => 'pa_mechanism',
        'Magnetic'     => 'pa_magnetic',
        'Side'         => 'pa_side',
        'Load'         => 'pa_load',
        'Availability' => 'pa_availability',
    ];

    if ( ! is_object( $product ) ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
    }

    echo '<div class="pa">';

    foreach ( $attr_list as $attr_title => $attr_name ) {
        show_attribute( $product, $attr_title, $attr_name );
    }

    echo '</div>';
}

/**
 * Show attribute.
 *
 * @param WC_Product $product    Product.
 * @param string     $attr_title Attribute title.
 * @param string     $attr_name  Attribute name.
 */
function show_attribute( $product, $attr_title, $attr_name ) {
    if ( 'sku' === $attr_name ) {
        $attr = (string) $product->get_sku();
    } else {
        $attr = $product->get_attribute( $attr_name );
    }

    if ( '' === $attr ) {
        return;
    }

    echo '<span>' . esc_html( $attr_title ) . ': </span><span class="pa-right">' . esc_html( $attr ) . '</span><br />';
}
```

В оптимизации код не нуждается. В WordPress и WooCommerce всё кешируется, и в базу делается только один раз один запрос для каждого продукта, чтобы считать все атрибуты товара.

Comment: Все отлично работает! Спасибо вам большое за помощь! А то, что страница с товаром у которого много атрибутов, может загружаться дольше, это от другого зависит?

Comment: Думаю, да. Другие факторы. Надо профилировать.